# Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE license not found

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xslt, saxon, license-key

We have a web application hosted on google app engine which main task is to do xslt processing using saxon. We obtained a license for the use of the saxon processor and placed the saxon-license.lic file next to the saxon9pe.jar file in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Everything is working great for years without any problems.

But lately we sometimes are getting the following error:

```
XPST0017 XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 23 in {saxon:parse($component)}:
Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://saxon.sf.net/}parse(). Saxon
extension functions require a Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE license
```

When I shut down the instance thats causing the problem, the error is solved and the app works for a few hours or days again.

It's almost like google appengine is "loosing" the license file during the life span of an instance.

Any idea what the underlying problem can be? 
Is there another way to pass the license file to the saxon server as a workaround?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a mailing list devoted to saxon, with the developers of saxon actively participating in that list.  You may get a (better) response to any licensing questions if you subscribe and post to the list.

Comment: Yes, it's hit-or-miss how quickly we notice a question posted here, whereas we try very hard to give a rapid response for questions raised at saxonica.plan.io, especially from paying customers!

Comment: Which Saxon software version are you running? Could it be this problem: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2064? (Which I think is the same issue as https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2050). Please raise a Saxon support request so we can work with you to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hi Michael, the problem is that sometimes the license file is recognized and sometimes not. I think it is a problem of Google AppEngine file mapping rather than Saxon. We're using saxon9pe. Is there an alternative way to setup the license key that doesn't depend of the filesystem of the platform environment? Is putting the license file in the class path a more robust solution?

Comment: Yes, putting the license file -- or rather, the directory containing it -- on the classpath is generally more reliable than relying on Saxon picking it up from being "next to" the JAR files.

Comment: Hi Michael, I did this, but still it fails to load the license file on rare occasions. If we could only load the license key in code...